# Assign excel formula to variable with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Dears,

I trying to assign a formula to a variable in order to grab the result of the formula but and i receive Run-time error '13'.

This is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim i As Long
Dim Result As Integer

For i = 2 To 5
   With Sheet1
     If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
        Result = "[=RIGHT(B" & i & ",LEN(B" & i & ")-((FIND(""-"",B" & i & 
         "))+1))]"
     End If
  End With
Next i
```

Also when i use this formula:

```
Result= [=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-((FIND("-",B2))+1))]
```

it works fine but i need to loop through column A and the usage of i it s necessary.

any help will appreciate!

Comment: That's not how VBA (or an eval block) works. Just use the VBA equivalents - `Right$`, 'Len`, and `InStr`.

Comment: `Result = Mid$(.Cells(i,2),Instr("-",.Cells(i,2))+1)`

Comment: `Result = Right$(WholeString, Len(WholeString) - InStr(WholeString, 
    PartString))`

@Comintern thanks for your help. i create this formula under your guidelines and i want to get the number after the "-".

Example: 0 - 200 i want the number 200.
is these formula correct or you have to suggest something else?